# How to rig and animate a 8-bit pixel stick figure?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I'm relatively new to Blender (use it before but I forgot almost everything) and I'm working on a simple "stick figure" model to make an animation. I want the arms and legs to behave like an 8-bit pixel sprite-like in old video games. What I want is for the arms and legs to "divide in pixels" and control those divisions to make the model look like an 8-bit sprite-like in the first image. What is the best way to create the arms and legs to rig and animate it in that way?

Thank you

PS. There's only a half model because I want to be symmetrical so I was going to copy/paste for the other half before rigging.

[image: IMG 1]

[image: Progress of my model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Remesh](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) modifier with "Blocks" selected like so...
[image]

Then you can animate your character like normal, while the Remesh option handles the pixelation of the mesh.

Comment: Uh, that may work. Thank you very much, I will try!

One question though, can I apply this modifier only to the arms and legs or has to be to all the objet? And if it's just the arms and legs, It won't be problematic with the rigging and the animation process?

Comment: Unfortunately it would have to be a separate mesh. This was the simplest option I could think of. Also, a note on your "copy/paste for the other half before rigging", you could simple use a 'mirror' modifer. This is common practice when modeling things that need symmetry.

Comment: Hello, Landon. I use the modifier you suggest but I get a single cube for result, even if I try changing the "Octree" doesn't look like your picture. And I ended up using the mirror modifier, thank you.